# Handling errors in Nodejs ReadableStream with vercel ai sdk

Tags: node.js, openai-api, vercel-ai

When handling API calls to openai and trying to stream it back to the client, there are two possible cases for errors:

1. Error occurs in the request, the stream does not begin between openai <-> my backend
   For this there is a nice documentation by vercel https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/guides/providers/openai#guide-handling-errors (tldr: wrap it in a try catch (duh))
2. Error occurs while the stream is ongoing. In this edge case the try catch block does not trigger. It could be a problem with sveltekit though?

Is there a way I can add an event listener or a "middleware" in the openai response stream, so that whenever an error does occur I can handle it accordingly?

```
const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model,
            stream: true,
            messages
        });

        // Convert the response into a friendly text-stream
        const stream = OpenAIStream(response);

        // Respond with the stream
        return new Response(stream);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error handling with node.js streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771220/error-handling-with-node-js-streams)

Comment: It does not, since I do not know how to detect an error while I pipe the stream.

Comment: That is literally what the question and its answers address